# data from database and show it in div using ajax codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have anchor tag, if i click anchor tag i want to show number with that id in one div in that page from database.

my view

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <a href="" onClick="return getVotes(userRef);" ><i class="fa fa-phone margin-right-10"></i> Call Doctor</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("gfdfg");
    function getVotes(userRef){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost/web/view-number',
            data: 'userRef=' + userRef,
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#content').html(data);

            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

controller:

```
          function viewNumber($userRef = NULL){
    //echo "fdsfd";exit;

        $this->load->model('DoctorSearch');
        $result = $this->DoctorSearch->getNumber($userRef);

        if ($result) {
            $data['records'] = $result;
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data['records']); die('test');
        }
        $this->load->view('pages/view-number', $data);
}
```

model:

```
      public function getNumber($userRef = NULL) {
    //print_r($userRef); die('test');
    $this->db->select('us.userRef,us.medicalRegNo');
    $this->db->from('tab_usersprofile as us');
    $this->db->where('us.userRef', '3mrTIaKjHAZ2BC7b');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    //echo $this->db->last_query(); die('test');
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;     
}
```

How to do, nothing is calling check my code and give the proper inout

Comment: what is `userRef`? how's you are getting it's value?

Comment: based on userRef(column name from database) i want to show number

Comment: Are you sure that value is coming? inspect that link through browser console and see what is the value there (i assume that `userRef` is php variable but you are treating it as java-script variable). It's not coming there for-sure

Comment: iam not sure, please modify my code and give proper code